# How to load fragment with recyclerview on start of the application?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have built a bottom navigation tab bar in android,it has 5 fragments but the problem is on start of the application it doesn't load the recyclerview list from firestore database. and this fragment is Home Fragment. but if I randomly open another tab and then comes the to the home tab the home tab list loads itself, but it does not load automatically on start of the app

below is the code. 
please assist

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "DocSnippets";

    private FirebaseAuth mauth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference UsersRef = db.collection("Users");
    private DocumentReference noteRef = db.document("Notebook/My First Note");
    private MySharedPreferences sp;
    private DocumentReference currentUserRef;

    private Button notificationList;


    private String mUserId, tokenId, currentUserProfilePic, currentUserName, currentUserSpinnerC;




    String currentUserID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sp = MySharedPreferences.getInstance(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
// currentUserID = mauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef =FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users");
        mUserId = mauth.getUid();
        tokenId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);



    }





    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;
            fragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();

                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                 //   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddPostActivity.class);
                   // startActivity(intent);
                    fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_post:
                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_postlist:
                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;

            }
            return loadFragment(fragment);
        }
    };


    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mauth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null)
        {
            SendUserToSignInActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            retrieveCurrentUserInfo();
            checkUserExistence();
        }

    }

    private void checkUserExistence() {

        final String current_user_id = mauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }


    private void SendUserToSignInActivity() {

        Intent signInIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
        signInIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(signInIntent);
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void retrieveCurrentUserInfo(){
        currentUserRef = db.collection("users").document(mUserId);
        currentUserRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()){
                        currentUserName = (String) document.getString("username");
                        currentUserProfilePic =(String) document.getString("profile_pic");
                        currentUserSpinnerC = (String) document.getString("spinnerC");


                        CircleImageView UserImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.current_user_Image);
                        Picasso.get()
                                .load(currentUserProfilePic)
                                .resize(50, 50)
                                .centerCrop()
                                .into(UserImage);

                        TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_user_name);
                        TextView spinnerC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_user_spinnerC);
                        username.setText(currentUserName);
                        spinnerC.setText(currentUserSpinnerC);

                    }
                }


            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment is not loaded at launching your activity, so add below code in your onCreate() method

```
loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the home fragment selection manually. Paste this at the end of the onCreate function of MainActivity.

```
View view = navigation.findViewById(R.id.navigation_home);
view.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading/calling any fragment in your onCreate() method.

**Try this way**

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     /**
      * Your code
      */

     loadFragment(LOAD_YOUR_FRAGMENT);
 }
```